# parse empty string using json

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I was wondering if there was a way to use `json.loads` in order to automatically convert an empty string in something else, such as `None`.

For example, given:

```
data = json.loads('{"foo":"5", "bar":""}')
```

I would like to have:

```
data = {"foo":"5", "bar":None}
```

Instead of:

```
data = {"foo":"5", "bar":""}
```

Comment: Why? Both are falsey so you could catch them

Comment: You could try some thing like `.replace("\"\"", "None")` on the string before loading it into json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = json.loads('{"foo":"5", "bar":""}')
res = {k: v if v != '' else None for k, v in data.items()}

{'foo': '5', 'bar': None}
```

This will only deal with the first level of a nested dictionary. You can use a recursive function to deal with the more generalised nested dictionary case:

```
def updater(d, inval, outval):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            updater(d[k], inval, outval)
        else:
            if v == '':
                d[k] = None
    return d

data = json.loads('{"foo":"5", "bar":"", "nested": {"test": "", "test2": "5"}}')

res = updater(data, '', None)

{'foo': '5', 'bar': None,
 'nested': {'test': None, 'test2': '5'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also accomplish this with the `json.loads` `object_hook` parameter. For example:

```
import json
import six


def empty_string2none(obj):
    for k, v in six.iteritems(obj):
        if v == '':
            obj[k] = None
    return obj


print(json.loads('{"foo":"5", "bar":"", "hello": {"world": ""}}',
                 object_hook=empty_string2none))
```

This will print

```
{'foo': '5', 'bar': None, 'hello': {'world': None}}
```

This way, you don't need additional recursion.

Answer (score 0):

> I did some trial and error and it is impossible to parse `None` into a String using `json.loads()` you will have to use `json.loads() with json.dumps()` like I do in this example:

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"foo":"5", "bar":"%r"}' %(None))
data2 = json.loads(json.dumps({'foo': 5, 'bar': None}))


if data2['bar'] is None:
    print('worked')
    print(data['bar'])
else:
    print('did not work')
```